# Minimizing Finite State Automaton

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, turing-machines, computation-theory

I am trying to minimize this DFA: http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/3006/dfac.png

Here's my minimized DFA: http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4131/mdfa.png

Am I correct?
Thanks

P.S.-This is homework. We are allowed to discuss the homework. I am not asking for the answer, I just want to know if I am on the right track or not as this is my first time dealing with state machines.

Comment: This seems to fit better on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com. Also, you can upload images to SO, please do not post links to sites that will die at some point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computer science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your proposed solution is not correct; you see the dfa you have constructed can accept the (otherwise non-acceptable) string "aac", that means you can't join states (11,15,17) and (15,17).

Looking at the original DFA I cannot think of any solution with less than 6 states; but yet again that means nothing ;).